# VSCode keybinding that inputs large amount of code (Python: Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'm currently trying to add a keybinding in Vscode that inputs multiple lines of code. Below is my current attempt at doing that – but it's not working due to some syntaxical errors. Would anyone know how I'm supposed to format this?

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+y",
        "command" : "type",
        "args": {
        "text": "
                leave1 = False
                while(leave1 == False):
                    try:
                        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '')
                    except Exception:
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                    else:
                        leave1 = True
                "
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: JSON string so not support multi line, create an array on individual strings for each line, use tab char for the indentation

Comment: @rioV8 How would that look like? I'm pretty new to all of this.

Comment: it is not a snippet, make a long string with `\n` characters

Comment: why don't you make snippets

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I did that and it's working – thank you. Can you post that as an answer to my question so I can accept it?

Comment: Wait but how would I do a reverse carriage return? I'm coding in python so indents matter, and using only \n wouldn't create a properly indented piece of code.

Comment: like I said in the first comment: `tab` characters

Comment: `\t` is a `tab` character.  Better to make it a true snippet (in a keybinding if you wish) as it would be very ugly as part of a `type` command and prone to error.